# Change div class when it becomes a certain height using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transforms

I have a div class that I'd like to change if one or more of the div classes within the page reaches a certain height. Here's what I'm working with.

```
.cube {transform: perspective( 1000px ) rotateX( 25deg ) rotateY( 40deg ) rotateZ( -20deg );
-webkit-transform: perspective( 1000px ) rotateX( 25deg ) rotateY( 40deg ) rotateZ( -20deg );}
```

When the content within the .cube makes it grow to a certain height and higher (like min-height), say 600px and higher, I'd like for the code to become this for any of the div classes that fit the critera

```
.cube {transform: perspective( 1000px ) rotateX( 0deg ) rotateY( 10deg ) rotateZ( 0deg );
-webkit-transform: perspective( 1000px ) rotateX( 0deg ) rotateY( 10deg ) rotateZ( 0deg );}
```

I was using this script just to test and see if anything would change, but it didn't work for me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.cube').resize(function() {
  if($(this).height() > 600){ $(this).css('-webkit-transform','none'); }  });
});
</script>
```

I'm not very experienced with javascript or jquery, but I've tinkered around with it a few times and I've had some success with very basic functions. Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hwys4zkc/)

Comment: Will the content of the div be changing dynamically? Or do you just need this to be detected on page load?

Comment: No. I just need for this to be detected on page load. Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the elements at page load, you can just do a jQuery each function for them on page load. The code looks like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
$('.cube').each(function() {
      if($(this).height() > 600){ $(this).addClass('large'); }  });
});
```

And, for ease, I added a `.cube.large` class to your CSS that contains your modified CSS for larger size ones. So, your CSS now looks like this:

```
.cube {transform: perspective( 1000px ) rotateX( 25deg ) rotateY( 40deg ) rotateZ( -20deg );
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 1000px ) rotateX( 25deg ) rotateY( 40deg ) rotateZ( -20deg );}
.cube.large {transform: perspective( 1000px ) rotateX( 0deg ) rotateY( 10deg ) rotateZ( 0deg );
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 1000px ) rotateX( 0deg ) rotateY( 10deg ) rotateZ( 0deg );}
```

Here's a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/76g2sLto/2/
Extra info: Using the resize jQuery function doesn't work because it only works on the window object. See http://api.jquery.com/resize/.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the dom element and change its class by using and put all the styles in the class so when it changes it will fit with it.

```
document.getElementById(your id).className = classname # class name you want
```